# How to expand multiple TitledPane of Accordion in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, accordion, expandable

I've a Accordion with having multiple titledPane and there has a lots of data within titledPane's ListView panel. I just want to expand all the titledPane of Accordion when searching the data. I don't know how to do this. any idea?

Here, I've attached my real project's screen shots and it shows actually what I want to do.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Quick answer: You can't.

The `Accordion` has an `expandedPane` property, that is a single `TitledPane`. There is no way for an `Accordion` to have multiple expanded panes.

Instead, you can use multiple `TitledPane`s directly (inside a `VBox` or similar), to get the behavior you want. Unfortunately, this won't look just like an `Accordion`, because `TitledPane`s by default uses different styling. But with some custom CSS (look at `caspian.css` to see how accordions are styled) you could make it look just like the panes look in an `Accordion`.

With slightly more work, you could work this into your own "multiple selection accordion" control, for easier reuse.

Comment: You don't understand my point sir, I just want to expand all the titled panes

Comment: @anondren Ok... Then, perhaps, you should explain it better. :-)

Comment: is there any way which I can do?

Comment: How can you be sure on that. are you a javaFX expert?

Comment: I know my english language is very poor, here maybe I want to say one thing and that's meaning being another. Anyway if this is true then I want to say very very sorry, Because I am noob for javaFX.

Answer (score 3):

Like harald said. You cant. But you can use multiple `TitledPane`'s in another Container. `VBox` for instance. Try this code snippet.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TitledPanes extends Application {

    public static void main(String [] args){ launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        HBox root = new HBox();

        VBox noaccordion = new VBox();
        noaccordion.getChildren().addAll(this.createPanes());

        VBox yesaccordion = new VBox();
        Accordion acc = new Accordion();
        acc.getPanes().addAll(this.createPanes());
        yesaccordion.getChildren().add(acc);

        root.getChildren().addAll(noaccordion, yesaccordion);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Collection<TitledPane> createPanes(){
        Collection<TitledPane> result = new ArrayList<TitledPane>();
        TitledPane tp = new TitledPane();
        tp.setText("Pane 1");
        tp.setContent(new TextArea("Random text..."));
        result.add(tp);
        tp = new TitledPane();
        tp.setText("Pane 2");
        tp.setContent(new TextArea("Random text..."));
        result.add(tp);
        tp = new TitledPane();
        tp.setText("Pane 3");
        tp.setContent(new TextArea("Random text..."));
        result.add(tp);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, at least *someone* listens to what I have to say...

Comment: I always listen to JavaFX experts. :P

Comment: thank you sir, but I don't want to go backword. Because It takes my whole time.

Comment: That comment doesn't seem to make any sense. If these answers do not answer your question (they both seem to), please edit the question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: @James_D I will try sir, that's why I've uploaded screen shots of my real projects.

Comment: This is a good *start* to an answer, but it doesn't actually solve the issue...with a 'real' multi-select accordion, the following hold true: - 1) The accordion either expands or manages the view space for the embedded views 2) scroll bars are an implementation detail of the view - they can be turned off and the entire view can be put into a scroll view 3) every box fully expands to the size of the whole view, if the accordion is fixed size, or it expands to the size of the content, if it is not fixed view.

Comment: The above solution does not satisfy 1,2, or 3, and from what I can tell TitledPane isn't nearly configurable enough to make this possible.